# How to make this horizontal menu to vertical menu, so that the menu would be on the right side and the sub-menus on its left side?

Tags: html, css

What to change in the CSS file? I hope somebody can help me.

```css
/*Set the parent <li>â€™s CSS position property to â€˜relativeâ€™.*/

ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 background: #1bc2a2;
}

/*The CSS to hide the sub menus.*/
li ul {
 display:none;
}
ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #fff;
}
ul li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}

/*Displays the dropdown menu on hover.*/
li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
 float: none;
}
li:hover a {
 background: #1bc2a2;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
 background: #2c3e50;
}
.main.navigation li ul li {
 border-top: 0;
}

/*Displays second level dropdown menus to the right of the first level dropdown menu.

*/
ul ul ul {
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu-hu">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>cigand.menu.nested.list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
     type="text/css"
          href="cigand.hu.menu.1.css" />
     
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main-navigation">
  <ul>
   <li><a>Városunk</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Köszöntő</a></li>
     <li><a>Földrajz</a></li>
     <li><a>Története</a></li>
     <li><a>Heraldika</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Önkormányzat</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Polgármesteri Hivatal</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Polgármester</a></li>
       <li><a>Alpolgármester</a></li>
       <li><a>Jegyző</a></li>
       <li><a>Titkárság</a></li>
       <li><a>Hatósági és Igazgatási Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Építésügyi és Városfejlesztési Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Pénzügyi Osztály</a></li>
       <li><a>Letölthető dokumentumok</a></li>
       <li><a>Pályázatok</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>EU</a></li>
         <li><a>ÁROP</a></li>
         <li><a>TIOP-1.2.3</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.1.0/A/11.</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.2.0/A/11-2011-0121</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-6.2.0/A/11-2011-0124</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-4.2.0/A/11-2011-0626</a></li>
         <li><a>EOP-5.5.0/K/14-2014-0031</a></li>
         <li><a>ÁROP-1.A.3-2014-2014-0116</a></li>
         <li><a>KEOP-5.7.0/15-2015-0275</a></li>
         <li><a>KÖFOP-1.2.1-VEKOP-16-2016-00280</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Képviselő-testület</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Képviselők</a></li>
       <li><a>Határozatok, Rendeletek</a></li>
       <li><a>Rendelet-tervezetek</a></li>
       <li><a>estületi ülések</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>RNÖ</a></li>
     <li><a>Telefonszámok</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Oktatás és Kultúra</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Oktatás</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Cigánd</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Óvoda</a></li>
         <li><a>Iskola</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a>Révleányvár</a></li>
       <li><a>Zemplénagárd</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Kultúra</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Művelődési Ház</a></li>
       <li><a>Városi Könyvtár</a></li>
       <li><a>Múzeumporta</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Iskolakonyha</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Egészségügy</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Háziorvosok</a></li>
     <li><a>Fogorvos</a></li>
     <li><a>Központi Orvosi Ügyelet</a></li>
     <li><a>Védőnői Szolgálat</a></li>
     <li><a>Járóbeteg Szakrendelő</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Hagyományok</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Múzeumporta</a></li>
     <li><a>Tájház</a></li>
     <li><a>Óvodamúzeum</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Sport</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Intézmények</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>Szabadidő Központ</a></li>
       <li><a>Műfüves-pálya</a></li>
       <li><a>Labdarúgó-pálya</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Cigánd SE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a>Kezdőlap</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
 </body> What to change?
</html>
Please read the text what I wrote! So the menu is going to the right side of the page and the sub-menus need open in its left side. How modify the code to get vertical menu system?
```

So the menu is going to the right side of the page and the sub-menus need open in its left side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you

```css
    ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: #1bc2a2;
    width: 260px;
    float:right;
}
    ul li {
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     background: #1bc2a2;
    }

    /*The CSS to hide the sub menus.*/
    li ul {
     display:none;
    }
    ul li a {
     display: block;
     padding: 1em;
     text-decoration: none;
     white-space: nowrap;
     color: #fff;
    }
    ul li a:hover {
     background: #2c3e50;
    }

    /*Displays the dropdown menu on hover.*/
    li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 260px;
}
    li:hover li {
     float: none;
    }
    li:hover a {
     background: #1bc2a2;
    }
    li:hover li a:hover {
     background: #2c3e50;
    }
    .main.navigation li ul li {
     border-top: 0;
    }

    /*Displays second level dropdown menus to the right of the first level dropdown menu.

    */
    ul ul ul {
     left: 100%;
     top: 0;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="main-navigation">
      <ul>
       <li><a>Városunk</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Köszöntő</a></li>
         <li><a>Földrajz</a></li>
         <li><a>Története</a></li>
         <li><a>Heraldika</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a>Önkormányzat</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Polgármesteri Hivatal</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a>Polgármester</a></li>
           <li><a>Alpolgármester</a></li>
           <li><a>Jegyző</a></li>
           <li><a>Titkárság</a></li>
           <li><a>Hatósági és Igazgatási Osztály</a></li>
           <li><a>Építésügyi és Városfejlesztési Osztály</a></li>
           <li><a>Pénzügyi Osztály</a></li>
           <li><a>Letölthető dokumentumok</a></li>
           <li><a>Pályázatok</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a>EU</a></li>
             <li><a>ÁROP</a></li>
             <li><a>TIOP-1.2.3</a></li>
             <li><a>KEOP-6.1.0/A/11.</a></li>
             <li><a>KEOP-6.2.0/A/11-2011-0121</a></li>
             <li><a>KEOP-6.2.0/A/11-2011-0124</a></li>
             <li><a>KEOP-4.2.0/A/11-2011-0626</a></li>
             <li><a>EOP-5.5.0/K/14-2014-0031</a></li>
             <li><a>ÁROP-1.A.3-2014-2014-0116</a></li>
             <li><a>KEOP-5.7.0/15-2015-0275</a></li>
             <li><a>KÖFOP-1.2.1-VEKOP-16-2016-00280</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a>Képviselő-testület</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a>Képviselők</a></li>
           <li><a>Határozatok, Rendeletek</a></li>
           <li><a>Rendelet-tervezetek</a></li>
           <li><a>estületi ülések</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a>RNÖ</a></li>
         <li><a>Telefonszámok</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a>Oktatás és Kultúra</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Oktatás</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a>Cigánd</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a>Óvoda</a></li>
             <li><a>Iskola</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a>Révleányvár</a></li>
           <li><a>Zemplénagárd</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a>Kultúra</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a>Művelődési Ház</a></li>
           <li><a>Városi Könyvtár</a></li>
           <li><a>Múzeumporta</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a>Iskolakonyha</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a>Egészségügy</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Háziorvosok</a></li>
         <li><a>Fogorvos</a></li>
         <li><a>Központi Orvosi Ügyelet</a></li>
         <li><a>Védőnői Szolgálat</a></li>
         <li><a>Járóbeteg Szakrendelő</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a>Hagyományok</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Múzeumporta</a></li>
         <li><a>Tájház</a></li>
         <li><a>Óvodamúzeum</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a>Sport</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a>Intézmények</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a>Szabadidő Központ</a></li>
           <li><a>Műfüves-pálya</a></li>
           <li><a>Labdarúgó-pálya</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a>Cigánd SE</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a>Kezdőlap</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How to do to put the menu to the right side of the display?

Comment: Just put ul { float: right}  li:hover > ul {right: 260px;} it will helps you as i updated the code also

Answer (score 0):

Right side of browser and open to the left ...
Not fully worked out but try to change this in your existing css ...

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #1bc2a2;
    float: right;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -200px;
    background: #1bc2a2;
}
li ul {
    margin-top: -50px;
    display:none;
}
...
ul ul ul {
    margin-left: -120px;
    top: 0;
}
```

You have to play with ul ul ul (with: nnn px; etc.)